# How to call an image asset path in CSS in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been having issues calling a background image in my CSS file. The issue ONLY occurs in production. I have spent a lot of time googling, and written many variations of the following code, but my production site simply does not seem to want to render it. What is wrong with the following code?

```
background: url(<%= image_path 'magnifyingglass.png' %>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a production issue related to precompiling assets in the asset pipeline. Check your configs and run rake assets:precompile before you deploy production.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was an asset pipeline issue. Thank you for making me look into it.